# unable to push updates to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have successfully pushed and pulled from a gitlab instance run by my company. However, seemingly at random, when I try to push updates I get the following error:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 648 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Enforcing Policies... 
remote: (refs/heads/dev) (bbb781) (7313fe)
remote: hooks/update:26:in `match': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
remote:     from hooks/update:26:in `block in check_message_format'
remote:     from hooks/update:24:in `each'
remote:     from hooks/update:24:in `check_message_format'
remote:     from hooks/update:33:in `<main>'
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/dev
To git@git.xxx.com:group-name/project-name.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.xxx.com:grou-name/project-name.git'
```

The only solution I've been able to come up with is to:

1. duplicate the branch (with a different name)
2. unpublish the old branch
3. delete the old branch
4. rename the branch to match the old, unpublished branch
5. `$ git push`

My method above can't be good, but it's the only way I can continue with my work. I have found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19784285/1438819 but I don't personally have access to gitlab on the server to attempt that fix.

More info:
I'm running git version 2.0.1,
Gitlab is version 7.1.1 facfec4

Comment: What's the branch name? Seems somehow to be a UTF8 issue.

Comment: it happens on multiple branches, but for example it started happening on a branch called '**dev**', and other branches called '**dev-alyssa**' or '**dev-someoneelse**'

Comment: Do you happen to have some hooks specified in your repository?